# Render django-cms page from other Django app

Tags: django, django-cms, django-apps

**Is there any way to render a django-cms page, from a view in another Django app, with a modified context?**

...I know that the "django-cms way" is to integrate your other apps inside django-cms via plugins and hooks. But I want to do it the other way around, as this is what makes more sense to me and leads to easier to reuse apps, and I found no documentation on how to do this. There should be a simple way to just call a django-cms view from my view and do some "voodoo" to make it work, right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why you'd want to call a 'django-cms view from my view'. What specifically are you trying to accomplish? This sentence is particularly confusing: "There should be a simple way to just call a django-cms view from my view and do some "voodoo" to make it work, right?" I can't think of a time that I've called a view from within another view...

Comment: @respondcreate what I actually need is to "render a django-cms page, from a view in another Django app", as I said. If there is an API for this, great, this is what I'd hope someone would know... if not, then even an ugly hacky way like calling a django-cms view from my view would be good... I've done call-view-from-view type of things when working with a new webapp I haven't had time to understand yet and had to make a feature work asap, then refactored once I figured out how things were set up...

Answer (score 3):

```
from cms.views import details

def show_some_page(request):
    return details(request, 'slug_of_page_to_show')
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a really good idea. The ugly hack desired by @NeuronQ would be to put the desired context variables into the request variable.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have solved this in the past is to do a get request on the URL with urllib2 (or requests), and extract the relevant pieces from the response.

```
...
site = Site.objects.get_current()
protocol = 'http' if DEBUG else 'https'
response = urllib2.urlopen('%s://%s%s' % (protocol,
    site.domain, page.get_absolute_url()))  # page is a Django-CMS page object
html_content = response.read()
response.close()
...
```

Each `page` object in Django-CMS has a `.get_absolute_url()` method, so that's how I got the URL to request programmatically, but as far as I know, the [Django-CMS API](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3.5/extending_cms/api_references.html) doesn't have a method to render a page.

If there's a different/better way to do this, I would love to see what it is.